# AngularJS/ng-grid - Updating array with splice doesn't updates UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I am trying to update **[ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)** with array `splice`.
 I have a plunk **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZRFvvo?p=preview)**.

Add button adds new row. Update button updates last item in the array.

1. Select a row & press update button. Nothing happens.
2. Press add button. Now UI gets updated with new element & as well as the previously updated element.
3. Same behavior gets repeated again & again.

I tried `$scope.$apply`. I get:

> “Error: $apply already in progress”

I even tried by placing `$scope.$apply` block inside a `setTimeout` call. Again the same error!

Any pointers!

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because data $watcher in ng-grid (incorrectly) compares the data object for reference, instead on object equality. You might remedy this by setting the third parameter to true in [data $watch function](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/ng-grid-2.0.7.debug.js#L3128) (line 3128):

```js
$scope.$parent.$watch(options.data, dataWatcher, true);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWeyTm?p=preview)

Comment: I'd give you 100 points if I could... this killed me when updating my remote data source.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me where to put the code in this question; so I just wanted to add that it was a mod to the grid.js file.

Comment: Do you know if this is fixed in the new version of ng-grid? I think I have a very similar problem.

Comment: I gave up on ngGrid. Consider trying [Smart Table](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table).

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE (2015-04-10)**

Angular has improved their code base (1.4.0), try the `$scope.$watchCollection` method first, and see if it works for you. ([Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection))

**ANSWER**

If you don't feel like hacking into a 3rd party library, you could add the hack in your code using:

```
$scope.updateData = function() {
  var data = angular.copy($scope.myData);
  data.splice(data.length - 1, 1, {name: 'UPDATED', age: '4'})
  $scope.myData = data;
};
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OI80lO?p=preview)

As @Stewie mentions, the problem is that for performance reasons `ngGrid` compares the data object superficially, and in the case of arrays, this is by reference. `ngGrid` also compares by the array length, so if the array doesn't change it's length the grid wont' get updated.

This solution creates a copy of the array (different place in memory) so that when angularjs `$watcher` checks for changes it will find a different object and run the `ngGrid` update callback.

**NOTE:** Because this solution creates a copy of the data array on every call to `updateData`, it could lead to performance problems if your data is too big, also Javascript doesn't have a great garbage collection.

**Old Incorrect Answer:**

<strike>`$timeout(angular.noop, 0);`</strike>

This simply sets a timeout to trigger a `$scope.$apply()` after the current one is done. A way of forcing a dirty check.

Comment: Can you get a Plunkr of this working? It's not working for me.

Comment: @Alain, you are right the `$timeout` answer doesn't work. It worked for me, but because I was in a different situation. I have updated my answer with a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ui-grid v3.0.0 (from an April 2015 unstable build).  I found this post and wanted to show others how I refreshed my grid after I removed a row from the grid data object using splice:

```
// Remove the row and refresh the grid.
$scope.myData.splice(rowIndex, 1);
$scope.gridApi.grid.refresh(true);
```

where my gridApi scope variable was set with this function:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
}
```