# Hide Angular ngGrid when no items are given

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I have an `ngGrid` that works fine so far. However, I would like to hide it when no items are given, so there is no data to show.

What I have tried is:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-show="items.length > 0">
</div>
```

This works, it actually hides the grid when `items.length` is equal to `0`, but once I add data to the `items` array, the grid won't show.

It also does not make a difference if I put the `ng-show` directive to an outer `div`:

```
<div ng-show="items.length > 0">
  <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

The responsible controller looks like this:

```
(function (root) {
  'use strict';

  root.app.controller('listItemsController', [
    '$scope', 'myService',
    function ($scope, myService) {
      $scope.items = [];

      $scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
          { field: 'id', displayName: 'Id' },
          { field: 'type', displayName: 'Type' },
          { field: 'value', displayName: 'Value' }
        ],
        data: 'items',
        enableRowSelection: false
      };

      $scope.$on('navigation::selectedItem', function (evt, selectedItem) {
        myService.getItems(selectedItem, function (err, items) {
          $scope.items = items;
        });
      });
    }
  ]);
})(window);
```

Getting the items works perfectly, and setting them on the grid works perfectly as well - *IF* I omit the `ng-show` directive.

**UPDATE**

Okay, it seems to be a problem with the initial rendering. As in the beginning, there are no items, the CSS `display` property is set to `none`. Apparently this avoids correct rendering. If you override this by using

```
ng-hide: {
  display:block!important;
}
```

in your styles, everything works as expected (except for the grid being hidden, of course).

Comment: Can you show the full code, or attach a plunker.

Comment: Well, the full code is just another `div` around this which has the controller. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Show us your controller.

Comment: Oh, of course, sorry! Done :-)

Comment: See if this helps: [AngularJS/ng-grid - Updating array with splice doesn't updates UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529559/angularjs-ng-grid-updating-array-with-splice-doesnt-updates-ui/17545152#17545152)

Comment: If it doesn't then try setting up a plunker. You `getItems` method looks weird, because the first parameter to a callback function is an error.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, and the usual way you write callbacks at least in Node.js (and that's where I am coming from).

Comment: Tried what you suggested, did not have any effect at all :-(

Answer (score 5):

I solved it using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`.

Comment: Can you show your code with ng-if? If the grid has no rows, I see the paging control outside the footer and it looks awful. Also, I can not seem to be able to update the grid with the data :( Only after I activate Dev. tools, the data starts showing. I downloaded the very latest version 2.02.12 and tried to apply suggestions in the mentioned thread to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

```
///first inject $timeout
$scope.$on('navigation::selectedItem', function (evt, selectedItem) {
        myService.getItems(selectedItem, function (err, items) {
          $timeout(function(){
               $scope.items = items;
          };
        });
      });
```

Comment: As I wrote, it works perfectly fine when I omit the `ng-show`. This definitely is not a `$apply` issue.