# How to update a row in angular ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I use ng-grid and I have an array to store my data.

`$scope.list = [{...},{...},{...}]`

Now I want to update the data in one object (namely in a row):

I tried `$scope.list[index] = {...}` and changed its value, but nothing in HTML is updated.

The ways below work for me, but they are not so pretty I think.

`arr = angular.copy($scope.list)
    arr[index] = {...}
    $scope.list = arr`

or

`$scope.list[index].attr_1 = sth;
    $scope.list[index].attr_2 = sthElse;
...`

Updated:

```
  $scope.pickProduct = ()->
    $scope.errorMessage = ''
    $http.post('/api/delivery_items/pick.json',
       barcode: $scope.scannedBarcode
    ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      $scope.scannedBarcode = ''
      angular.forEach $scope.picklist, (row, index) ->
        if row.id == data.id
          # I update the data but it doesn't change the row in HTML
          $scope.picklist[index] = data.delivery_item
    ).error((data, status) ->
      if data.status is 'nok'
        $scope.scannedBarcode = ''
        $scope.errorMessage = data.message
    )
```

Comment: Can you show more code where you try `$scope.list[index] = {...}`? Do you try to use `$scope.$apply()` after changing the value?

Comment: This issue is discussed and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529559/angularjs-ng-grid-updating-array-with-splice-doesnt-updates-ui

Comment: See naegers answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711933/scope-confusion-in-ng-grid-when-returning-data-from-modal

Comment: i thing this link is helpfull[Updating selected rows into ng-grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116302/updating-selected-rows-into-ng-grid)