# Scope confusion in ng-grid when returning data from modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-grid

Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aqLnno?p=preview

I have a list of persons (`$scope.persons`) to be displayed in a ng-grid. Each line has a edit button. When the user clicks on the button (`ng-click="edit(row)"`) (see code below), I copy the displayed person (`angular.copy(row.entity)`) and open a modal dialog. ... so far so good.

When the user clicks "Cancel" on the modal, nothing happens. When the user clicks "Save" on the model, the modified person is returned and should be "reintegrated" in `$scope.persons`.

This is where the problem starts: I search in `$scope.persons` to find the correct person and replace it with the person returned from the modal. The log statements show the `$scope.persons` before and after the modification and everything looks good. However, the ng-grid doesn't seem to care. It still operates on a different (the old) `$scope.persons`.

If I uncomment the `row.entity = person` and set the row directly, everything looks fine in the ng-grid. However, as the underlying data model is not changed correctly, a resort will bring up the old (un-modified) person again.

Here is the code of my edit function:

```
$scope.edit = function(row) {
  $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'personEdit.html',
    backdrop: true,
    windowClass: 'modal',
    controller: 'PersonModalInstanceCtrl',
    resolve: {
      person: function() {
        return angular.copy(row.entity);
      }
    }
  })
    .result.then(function(person) {
      $log.log('Edited person: ' + JSON.stringify(person));
      angular.forEach($scope.persons, function(p, index) {
        $log.log('p: ' + JSON.stringify(p) + ' index: ' + index);
        if (p.id == row.entity.id) {
          $log.log('scope: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.persons));
          $scope.persons[index] = person;
        }
      });
      $log.log('scope: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.persons));
      // row.entity = person;
    }, function() {});
};
```

What am I doing wrong with my scopes?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can't find the button in the plunker

Comment: The edit button is in the personCellTemplate.html which gets included in the $scope.gridOptions under ColumnDefs as an additional column: {field: 'Actions', cellTemplate: 'personCellTemplate.html'}. But this part works: the modal opens, editing is possible and it does correctly return the edited person.

Comment: All it says is `ReferenceError: $modal is not defined`

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/aqLnno?p=preview works for me ... (ok i might have messed around with the freeze button. does it work now???)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. Again something learnt. The answer of jantimon pointed me in the right direction. But I didn't like how he changed my $scope.persons array (I get this array from a RESTful GET and liked the fact that I can just use the returned JSON as $scope.persons without modification).

Anyway, here is the explanation:

When copying my person from the original $scope.persons list I created a new object in a new memory location:

```
angular.copy(row.entity)
```

This is necessary as the user can "Cancel" his edit.

When the user clicks "Save" I have to take this copied person and put it back to $scope.persons instead of the old one. I did this with:

```
$scope.persons[index] = person;
```

Although this is correct and gives the desired result (as the log statements show), the persons[index] now points to a different memory location.

BUT: ng-grid internally still points to the old memory location! ng-grid has not memorized the pointer (person[index]) as the data model but instead has memorized the destination of the original pointer (*person[index]) [sorry for my C-stylish talking]. I would consider this a BUG in ng-grid IMHO.

So all I need to do is copy the new person back to the exact same memory location it has come from. Luckily, there is an angular directive for that:

```
angular.extend($scope.persons[index], person);
```

If you just replace $scope.persons[index] = person; with angular.extend($scope.persons[index], person); everything works fine.

Comment: Is there a fast way of searching the index of the person within $scope.persons ?

Comment: I simply iterate through the array to find the right person (angular.forEach) .. not really efficient but works and my array is at most a few hundred persons (usually a lot less).

Comment: ah, I was doing the same but wanted to ask just to be sure that other people where doing the same (a O(n) search)... there must be functions for searching without writing the entire for, aren't there any? like in C# you have LINQ and you stop writing fors all the time, eg: `someArray.Where(e => e.personId == id)`

Comment: Well, I am not really a JavaScript person. But there should be something like a HashMap that gives you O(1) access to the right person ...

Comment: yes, every list in javascript can be used as a map too... but for this case maybe underscore.js would help (this is my conclusion)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ng-grid isn't updating correctly when you are changing the array

You might keep the pointer of the row entity like in this example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0lDoKOg4kXXa51NlSuMg?p=preview

It uses `$scope.persons[index].data = person.data;` instead of `$scope.persons[index] = person;`.

Comment: hmm. This one does indeed work. Thank you. But i have no clue why. And as you might guess, I get my persons as a restful GET which returns a JSON array of objects and it's strange I have to rearrange this structure by introducing the 'data' field.

Comment: I didn't like the fact that I had to change the persons array I get from my REST-Service. But your answer pointed me in the right direction (see my own answer). Wouldn't have found it without you. Thanks! ... Do you agree that the described behaviour is a bug in ng-grid? I come from a Java/C/C++ background, Javascript and Angular are new to me...

Comment: File a bug - this is sth Angular can handle so ng-grid should also support it: http://plnkr.co/edit/JNGh7mjU8WqeNG3RHbiM?p=preview