# Angular UI datepicker not updating

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have tried to extend the UI datepicker with previous and next day buttons.

As you can see from the plunker I can change the model either by using the datepicker or the prev/next buttons. But when the model is changed with the prev/next buttons, the datepicker ist not updated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/k1flklFny5BoX6zdwyWJ?p=preview

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" 
        datepicker-popup="{{ctrl.format}}" ng-model="ctrl.dt" 
        is-open="ctrl.opened" datepicker-options="ctrl.dateOptions" 
        ng-required="true" close-text="Close" /> 
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.open($event)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried several approaches already (including $scope and the demonstrated controller as syntax) but it simply does not work. Any ideas?

PS: I tried very hard to have prev button, datepicker, next button in one line, centered, the datepicker occupying just enough space it needs. If anyone has an idea how to accomplish that, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why, but seems that ngModel doesn't react when Date object changed itself. But it changed if you assign to scope property new instance of Date.

Try this:

```
this.prevDay = function() {
    this.dt = getPrevNextDate(this.dt, -1);
};

this.nextDay = function() {
    this.dt = getPrevNextDate(this.dt, 1);
};

function getPrevNextDate(date, increment)
{
  var newDate = new Date();
  newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + increment);
  return newDate;
}
```

And better to cache `this` into some variable like `var self = this` at top of controller function and use `self` variable instead of `this`

This way you will avoid error in this line:

```
$log.log('GET api/v1/person/' + this.person.id + '/entry returned: ' + data.length + ' entries')
```

Comment: I did not get the last part with the this and self. why do i need var self = this?

Comment: Just add this line into person request `success` handler: `console.dir(this)` anf you'll see yourself

Comment: ah I see .. inside the success handler is a callback so i am no longer in my Ctrl class and this points somewhere else. Thank you

Comment: For the answer itsself. It works. Thanks a lot!! you have no idea how many hours I already spent fumbling around with this. Last week I had a similar question and there I changed my model by reassigning a property to point to a new object instead of altering the existing object (the exact opposite like here): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711933/scope-confusion-in-ng-grid-when-returning-data-from-modal .... this sucks!! or am I just too stupid???

Comment: hi. I just tried your solution for datepicker, but it seems that it works well only during one month, because when I go to prev or next month, it jumps back to first month. For example  if I click prev - 1 Jun, 31 May, 30 Jun ... Do you have any ideas how can I fix this?